# Distributing Docker Container Application for Desktop Environment

Tags: python, mongodb, deployment, docker, user-friendly

I have developed a web-based application for end-users that resides in a `docker` container. The container itself hosts a few `python` dependencies, a few public repositories, and a `flask` based web front-end with a `MongoDB` back-end that is started when the container is initialized.

It's fairly straightforward to download the container and run it on a `docker` host. However, most `docker` hosts (if not all) are not free.

Therefore, if an end-user wanted to use my application off the cloud they would have to download and install `docker` and associated dependencies on their local machine prior to being able to use the image (which is even more complicated on a system like Windows or Mac OSX)

With that being said, my question is: Is there any tool that has been developed to help ease this requirement on the end-user for deployment to users local desktop environments? I understand installing and using `docker` is not THAT hard, but some people are still very afraid of command-lines and I was hoping to find a method that would help alleviate some of these 'scary' requirements.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but you may be interested in https://sandstorm.io/ (Linux-only, does not use docker)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looks very close to what I'm trying to do, just unfortunate it alienates most of my end-user base (Windows/Mac OSX).

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [Boot2Docker](http://boot2docker.io/)?  It packages up the Docker CLI compiled for Windows or OSX, a VirtualBox VM to run Linux for the containers, with an easy-to-use installer.

Also https://kitematic.com adds more point-and-click for Mac users.

Overall, however, Docker is a developer/devops tool, and I haven't seen much aimed at helping non-technical folks use it.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was referring to with the CLI requirements. The installation procedure is not that straight forward and it provides a huge gateway to my application. I was really hoping for a 'double-click start' like solution for running the Docker container. To put it in perspective, this application is intended to be used by everyday users, not developers, so anything like Boot2Docker is out of the question.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise you were targeting non-technical users. Have added another link.